# Keeping a (title-) Paragraph and a Table together on one page?

Tags: java, itext

I'm generating a PDF document with iText 5.5.8
In this document there are numbered paragraphs that only contain a title Paragraph and a PdfPTable.

```
    for (Item item : getItems()) {
        Paragraph title = new Paragraph();
        Chunk chunk = new Chunk(new Chunk(getIcon(item), 0, 0));
        addBookmark(item, chunk);
        title.add(chunk);
        Chunk chunk2 = new Chunk(getName(item), catFont_u);
        title.add(chunk2);
        title.setSpacingBefore(20);
        title.setSpacingAfter(14);
        PdfPTable table = createTable(item); // can be more than a page!
        table.setKeepTogether(true);
        Section subSection = chapter.addSection(title);
        subSection.add(table);
    }
```

Now when the table is larger that te space left in the rest of the page, the table will be 'moved' to the next page (setKeepTogether()). This is good.
However, I want the title Paragraph to always be on the same page as the PdfPTable. So the title Paragraph should be moved to the next page also.

How do I accomplish this?

Thanks,

Carel

Answer (score 0):

You can create an outer table of one column. then add your paragraph(title). after that create another table innerTable, here you can place your data, then add inner table to a cell and then add that cell to outer table. So that your title and table will be together, and also make outer table setsplitLate(false).

Answer (score 0):

iText 7.2.5, java11:

```
static Table createKeepTogetherContainer( List<IBlockElement> aLines )
{
    Table result = new Table( 1 )
            .setWidth( UnitValue.createPercentValue( 100 ) )
            .setPadding( 0 )
            .setMargin( 0 )
            .setBorder( Border.NO_BORDER )
            .setKeepTogether( true );
    aLines.forEach( l -> result.addCell( new Cell()
                                         .add( l )
                                         .setPadding( 0 )
                                         .setMargin( 0 )
                                         .setBorder( Border.NO_BORDER )
                                         ) );
    return result;
}
```